# How do I fix missing git remote details?

Tags: git, repository

Some repository clones I have allow me to do this:

```
% git pull
% git push
```

But other repositories require me to type:

```
% git pull origin master
% git push origin master
```

I think I am missing something in the latter case - does anyone know what is (not) going on here?  I am using the latest git version, just obviously not using it well.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you cd into your repository directory and then open up your **.git/config** file in an editor.

Append this to the end of the file:

```
[branch "master"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/master
```

This is pretty much just an alias so git knows by default to pull from origin master.

Answer (score 13):

Or if you prefer, you can do the same thing Brian Gianforcaro proposed from the command line:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge  refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, to avoid having to do `git push master`, you can specify what branches to push in your Git config file, like so:

```
[remote "origin"]
        ...
        push = master
```