# Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I know how to make a new branch that tracks remote branches, but **how do I make an existing branch track a remote branch?**

I know I can just edit the `.git/config` file, but it seems there should be an easier way.

Comment: As noted below, for an existing branch, you can use `git push -u origin branch-name`.

Comment: If local branch is current branch, and local branch is not already tracking a remote, `git pull` will often provide helpful messages about the appropriate command to set tracking information

Comment: It's annoying when one is learning git to be shown a link to the git documentation. That documentation appears to be written for people that **already** know what they are doing with git.

Comment: as of Git 2.10 you should first checkout to intended local branch and then do this `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/<branch>`

Comment: `--set-upstream` produces an error: `fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead.` so `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/<branch name>` is the current command that works.

Comment: For people getting this SO question as first hit searching for `"git remote add" "tracking"`: I needed to add a new remote tracking an existing branch, which I solved with `git remote add gitlab https://user@gitlab.com/group/subgroup/repository.git -t master` followed by `git push gitlab`. Works with `git version 2.18.0`. The `-t` is for `tracking` as there is no `--tracking` according to `man git remote add`

Comment: it is definitely frustrating that checking out out a branch or initiating gitflow intermittently does not link the branch to the remote source and will randomly throw errors instead of completing normal commands. This breaks setup scripts, or baffles newbies who are told "follow these commands to get started".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Comment: latest, git branch -u origin/<remote branch name you want to track>

Answer (score 4852, accepted):

Given a branch `foo` and a remote `upstream`:

**As of Git 1.8.0:**

```
git branch -u upstream/foo
```

Or, if local branch `foo` is not the current branch:

```
git branch -u upstream/foo foo
```

Or, if you like to type longer commands, these are equivalent to the above two:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/foo

git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/foo foo
```

**As of Git 1.7.0 (before 1.8.0):**

```
git branch --set-upstream foo upstream/foo
```

**Notes:**

- All of the above commands will cause local branch `foo` to track remote branch `foo` from remote `upstream`.
- The old (1.7.x) syntax is deprecated in favor of the new (1.8+) syntax.  The new syntax is intended to be more intuitive and easier to remember.
- Defining an upstream branch will fail when run against newly-created remotes that have not already been fetched. In that case, run `git fetch upstream` beforehand.

---

See also: [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/95706)

Comment: Is "upstream" the name of the remote? i.e. what most would call "origin" by default?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes. `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master` would be equivalent to what is automatically done when you initially clone a repository.

Comment: On a related note, adding this to your gitconfig is awesome: "[push] default=tracking"  this will make it so that pushes will go the same place that pulls come from :)

Comment: I get "fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/master'."

Comment: Just in case someone didn't know: "git branch -a -v" shows what branches you have available, "git remote -v" shows what remotes you have.

Comment: joachim: do you have a remote called "origin" with a branch "master" in it? `git branch -r` will show your remote branches.

Comment: joachim: I got the same error.  In my case, I was changing servers for remote origin, so I renamed the remote.  Then there was no more origin/master remote branch, so I needed to do this:

    git fetch origin
    git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
    git pull

Comment: `git push -u origin foo` [via](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time/6089415#6089415)

Comment: @PaulHedderly (just to confirm), this command literally does nothing more than what your answer does?

Comment: @joachim same error, I simply had to start by typing "git push origin master", because at first there was no master branch in the remote origin.

Comment: For future reference: if you get "fatal: Ambigious object name: <your object name>", add `remotes/` before it. So instead of `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`, do `git branch --set-upstream master remotes/origin/master`.

Comment: @ErikHesselink I still get the ambiguous error, even with remotes/origin/master: warning: refname 'remotes/origin/master' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'remotes/origin/master'.

Comment: @J.PabloFernández: Try adding 'refs/' in front of the remote branch name, making it 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.

Comment: @ErikHesselink that din't help: git branch --set-upstream master refs/remotes/origin/master
error: Not tracking: ambiguous information for ref refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: @ErikHesselink nevermind... somehow I ended up with a messed up repo.

Comment: Also in recent `git`, if you have fetched new remote branch and don't have a local branch for it, then `git checkout` with the same branchname will auto created a tracking branch

Comment: To display your origin and upstream, type `git remote -v`

Comment: @joachim See: [Why does git not recognize “origin/master” as a valid object name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14717957/1851186)

Comment: I use Git 1.8.1.2 and it gives me:
`The --set-upstream flag is deprecated and will be removed. Consider using --track or --set-upstream-to`

Comment: @ChrisFrancis  Git never ceases to amaze me with its powerful and flexible features, accessed with a cryptic but surprisingly simple syntax.  Sometimes when I come here I feel like I'm at Hogwarts learning new spells...

Comment: This actually works with git-svn as well, though you may need to do a little bit of work (like a regular git rebase) to get your local branch to no longer be diverged from the new svn branch.

Comment: @AndrewVit I always set my remote repo (e.g. GitHub) to `origin` and the repo I forked from as `upstream`. Then I `git fetch upstream` and `git branch -u origin/foo`

Comment: This doesn't work correctly in git 2.8.1. It tries to create a local branch called upstream/foo, even when upstream is a remote repo.

Comment: The 1st and 3rd solutions will only work when `foo` is the current branch [according to the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--ultupstreamgt), even [in 1.8](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch/1.8.0#git-branch--ultupstreamgt). Since the question does not specify whether the "existing branch" is checked out, I feel that `git branch -u upstream/foo` and `git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/foo` should be **removed** from this answer.

Comment: `git branch -u upstream/foo` works for me , not try others.

Comment: Also it can be used as: `git branch -u origin/branch_name`

Comment: Why don't git push to this branch by default? I have a `sth` branch, tracking a remote's `master`. `git push` and `git push personal master` don't work, but a lengthy `git push rem HEAD:master` works.

Comment: I feel that this answer is missing some important steps. Because executing for example `git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/foo` leads to error `the requested upstream branch 'upstream/foo' does not exist`

Comment: @user7860670 this is because in your case you don't have an upstream branch with name `upstream/foo`, you need to check the remote verbose with `git remote -v` to display the remote verbose name(s) list you have, let's assume it is `origin`. Then to link the `origin/dev` branch to my local `foo` branch I can type 'git branch -u origin/dev foo`. In case the local branch and the remote one is `foo` then `git branch -u origin/foo`.

Comment: @Cotton's command worked for me where others did not

Answer (score 274):

You can do the following (assuming you are checked out on master and want to push to a remote branch master):

Set up the 'remote' if you don't have it already

```
git remote add origin ssh://...
```

Now configure master to know to track:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

And push:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: it is really required the remote and the branch in the push? I mean, you only need it if your checked out branch is not the one you want to push, right ?

Comment: Yes - but from memory you may need to be explicit for the first push. Can easily be tested of course... :)

Comment: +1 This is the answer for Windows users who are stuck with the msysgit "preview" that is pre 1.8. Thanks for that.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. When I tried the accepted answer, to set the upstream remote for an existing branch, I got: `error: the requested upstream branch 'upstream/master' does not exist`.

Comment: @SteveK that's most likely because your upstream is called `origin` and not `upstream`.

Comment: Note that this translates to the following if you want to just manually update the .git/config file:

```[branch "master"]  
    remote = origin  
    merge = refs/heads/master```

Answer (score 211):

I do this as a side-effect of pushing with the `-u` option as in

```
$ git push -u origin branch-name
```

The equivalent long option is `--set-upstream`.

The `git-branch` command also understands `--set-upstream`, but its use can be confusing. [Version 1.8.0](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/10/1/419) modifies the interface.

> `git branch --set-upstream` is deprecated and may be removed in a relatively distant future.  `git branch [-u|--set-upstream-to]` has been introduced with a saner order of arguments.
>
> …
>
> It was tempting to say `git branch --set-upstream origin/master`, but that tells Git to arrange the local branch "origin/master" to integrate with the currently checked-out branch, which is highly unlikely to be what the user meant. The option is deprecated; use the new `--set-upstream-to` (with a short-and-sweet `-u`) option instead.

Say you have a local `foo` branch checked out and want it to use a branch by the same name as its upstream. Make this happen with

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/foo
```

Answer (score 75):

For Git versions 1.8.0 and higher:

Actually for the accepted answer to work:

```bash
git remote add upstream <remote-url>
git fetch upstream
git branch -f --track qa upstream/qa
# OR Git version 1.8.0 and higher:
git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/qa
# Gitversions lower than 1.8.0
git branch --set-upstream qa upstream/qa
```

Comment: The local branch was already tracking a branch, so we can assume the remote repo was already added.

Comment: Dopplerganger: See joachim's comment to the accepted answer.  Anyway assumptions readily differ - it what makes things so interesting ;)

Answer (score 61):

You might find the [`git_remote_branch`](http://github.com/webmat/git_remote_branch) tool useful. It offers simple commands for creating, publishing, deleting, tracking & renaming remote branches. One nice feature is that you can ask a `grb` command to explain what git commands it would execute.

```bash
grb explain create my_branch github
# git_remote_branch version 0.3.0

# List of operations to do to create a new remote branch and track it locally:
git push github master:refs/heads/my_branch
git fetch github
git branch --track my_branch github/my_branch
git checkout my_branch
```

Comment: grb is a ruby gem that can be accessed as explained on [their github](https://github.com/webmat/git_remote_branch)

Comment: The OP is asking question about Git itself. So don't introduce a new tool would probably be better.

Comment: grb is an alias for git-rebase on my macOS installation. I didn't do this :)

Answer (score 53):

1- update your local meta-data using  : **git fetch --all**

[image]

2- show your remote and local branches using : **git branch -a**
, see the following Screenshot

[image]

3- switch to target branch , that you want to linked with the remote: using

**git checkout branchName**

example :

[image]

4- Link your local branch to a remote branch using:

**git branch --set-upstream-to  nameOfRemoteBranch**

N.B  : **nameOfRemoteBranch** : to copy from the output of step 2 " git branch -r "

Example of use:

[image]

Comment: Mostly easy and simple answer.

Comment: Why is this not the top answer already? Can't believe it's 2023 and git commands are so unnecessarily complex. All I wanted to do was pull a remote branch, this answer was the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 49):

I believe that in as early as Git 1.5.x you could make a local branch `$BRANCH` track a remote branch `origin/$BRANCH`, like this.

Given that `$BRANCH` and `origin/$BRANCH` exist, and you've not currently checked out `$BRANCH` (switch away if you have), do:

```
git branch -f --track $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH
```

This recreates `$BRANCH` as a tracking branch. The `-f` forces the creation despite `$BRANCH` existing already. `--track` is optional if the usual defaults are in place (that is, the git-config parameter `branch.autosetupmerge` is true).

Note, if `origin/$BRANCH` doesn't exist yet, you can create it by pushing your local `$BRANCH` into the remote repository with:

```
git push origin $BRANCH
```

Followed by the previous command to promote the local branch into a tracking branch.

Comment: `git push origin $BRANCH` was what I was looking for.

Comment: After trying all sorts of solutions, including setting up an upstream as described above nothing worked. All I wanted to do is pull 1 new commit into my local branch from a remote one and I didn't setup tracking initially. The command `git branch -f --track $BRANCH origin/$BRANCH` does the trick.

Answer (score 29):

Make sure you run :

```
git config push.default tracking
```

to be able to push trouble free

Comment: This could be convenient. We could note, however, that according to `git-config(1)` manual page, `tracking` is deprecated synonym of `upstream`.

Comment: Beware! After branching a local branch from origin master with something like `git checkout -b mybranch origin/master`, and making changes on your local branch, **the above will push to master** on the remote when you run `git push`. For most people this would be unexpected.

Answer (score 27):

Editing `.git/config` is probably the easiest and fastest way. That's what the Git commands for handling remote branches are doing, anyway.

If you don't want to muck with the file by hand (and it's not that hard to do), you can always use `git config` to do it...but again, that's just going to edit the `.git/config` file, anyway.

There are, of course, ways to automatically track a remote branch when using `git checkout` (by passing the `--track` flag, for example), but these commands work with *new* branches, not existing ones.

Answer (score 22):

In very short

```
git branch --set-upstream yourLocalBranchName origin/develop
```

This will make your `yourLocalBranchName` track the remote branch called `develop`.

Comment: @Quincy Check [greg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694311/321973) - use `git push -u origin branch` (or `--set-upstream-to`) instead

Comment: @MadNik, what is the difference between `--set-upstream` and `--track`? I don't quite understand why I should use one over the other.

Answer (score 18):

For 1.6.x, it can be done using the [git_remote_branch](http://github.com/webmat/git_remote_branch) tool:

```
grb track foo upstream
```

That will cause Git to make `foo` track `upstream/foo`.

Answer (score 17):

I use the following command (Suppose your local branch name is "branch-name-local" and remote branch name is "branch-name-remote"):

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch-name-remote branch-name-local
```

If both local and remote branches have the same name, then just do the following:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch-name branch-name
```

Comment: You reversed "branch-name" and "origin/branch-name" on the command line. The upstream comes before the local.

Comment: @maharvey67 you are right, thanks. Edited the answer.

Comment: This was gold, thank you, also because none of the options within the accepted answer are ok when you have slashes in the branch name

Answer (score 11):

For creating new branch, we could use following command

```
 git checkout --track -b example origin/example
```

For the already created branch to create link between remote then from that branch use below command

```
 git branch -u origin/remote-branch-name
```

Answer (score 10):

### Use '--track' Option

- After a `git pull` :

  `git checkout --track <remote-branch-name>`
- Or:

  `git fetch && git checkout <branch-name>`

Answer (score 9):

Here, using `github` and `git version 2.1.4`, just do:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

And remotes come by itelsef, even if not linked locally:

```
$ git remote show origin

* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:user/repo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:user/repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop tracked         <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    master  tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

But of course, still no local branch:

```
$ git branch
* master                  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

See? Now if you just checkout develp, it will do the magic automatically:

```
$ git checkout develop
Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'develop'
```

So easy!

---

**Summary.** Just run this 2 commands:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
$ git checkout develop
```

Comment: An excellent example of my identical use case.  Despite no sign of a local 'develop' branch, when I checked out the 'develop' branch that branch appears and is magically set up to track the remote branch 'develop' from origin.  I appreciate the step by step example and explanation!

Answer (score 8):

In case you got **"error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/foo' does not exist"** after running:

```
git branch -u origin/foo
```

---

1. Make sure `origin` does have a `foo` branch.
2. Make sure the `remote.origin.fetch` variable is set to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`:

```sh
$ git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

3. Run `git fetch -v`. You should see git updating from `origin/foo`:

```sh
$ git fetch -v
From github.com:davidhcefx/test
 * [new branch]      foo             -> origin/foo
 = [up to date]      master          -> origin/master
```

4. Upon success, `git branch -avv` will show square brackets, indicating tracked remote branches:

```sh
$ git branch -u origin/foo
branch 'foo' set up to track 'origin/foo'.
$ git branch -avv
* foo                            92c5ada [origin/foo] Initial commit
  master                         92c5ada [origin/master] Initial commit
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a direct answer to this question, but I wanted to leave a note here for anyone who may be having the same issue as me when trying to configure an upstream branch.

Be wary of **push.default**.

With older git versions, the default was **matching**, which would cause very undesirable behaviour if you have, for example:

Local branch "master" tracking to origin/master

Remote branch "upstream" tracking to upstream/master

If you tried to "git push" when on the "upstream" branch, with **push.default matching** git would automatically try to merge the local branch "master" into "upstream/master", causing a whole lot of chaos.

This gives more sane behaviour:

git config --global push.default upstream

Comment: You did not leave this in vain.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For git version `2.25.1`, use the command:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <local_branch_name>
```

Comment: This could be inconvenient if you don't plan to push your changes yet!

Answer (score 5):

In a somewhat related way I was trying to add a remote tracking branch to an existing branch, but did not have access to that remote repository on the system where I wanted to add that remote tracking branch on (because I frequently export a copy of this repo via sneakernet to another system that has the access to push to that remote). I found that there was no way to force adding a remote branch on the local that hadn't been fetched yet (so local did not know that the branch existed on the remote and I would get the error: `the requested upstream branch 'origin/remotebranchname' does not exist`).

In the end I managed to add the new, previously unknown remote branch (without fetching) by adding a new head file at `.git/refs/remotes/origin/remotebranchname` and then copying the ref (eyeballing was quickest, lame as it was ;-) from the system with access to the origin repo to the workstation (with the local repo where I was adding the remote branch on).

Once that was done, I could then use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/remotebranchname`

Answer (score 4):

or simply by  :

switch to the branch if you are not in it already:

```
[za]$ git checkout branch_name
```

run

```
[za]$ git branch --set-upstream origin branch_name
Branch origin set up to track local branch brnach_name by rebasing.
```

and you ready to :

```
 [za]$ git push origin branch_name
```

You can alawys take a look at the config file to see what is tracking what by running:

```
 [za]$ git config -e
```

It's also nice to know this, it shows which branches are tracked and which ones are not. :

```
  [za]$ git remote show origin
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who, like me, just wants to sync up your local branch name with the remote branch name, here's a handy command:

```
git branch -u origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Answer (score 0):

To **avoid remembering** what you need to do each time you get the message:

> Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1)
>   for details.
>   .....

You can use the following script which sets **origin as upstream** for the **current branch** you are in.

In my case I **almost never** set **something else than origin** as the **default upstream**. Also I almost always keep the same branch name for local and remote branch. So the following fits me:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# scriptname: git-branch-set-originupstream
current_branch="$(git branch | grep -oP '(?<=^\* )(.*)$')"
upstream="origin/$current_branch"
git branch -u "$upstream"
```

Comment: In git 2.37+, you probably want `git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge simple` and `git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true`. At checkout you will get tracking only if the local branch name matches the remote, and at `git push` time a new local branch will create the new remote branch, with tracking, automatically.

Answer (score -2):

This would work too

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=/< remote>/< branch> < localbranch>
```