# Getting existing git branches to track remote branches

Tags: git

My usual workflow when working with git, is something like this:

1. create a local repository
2. do some work in that repository, add/change files etc.
3. decide that I want a central remote location for the repository, and create one
4. push all the commits from my local repository to this new remote repository

Now, however, I want to be able to `push` and `pull` from this remote repository without having to specify where I'm pushing to or pulling from; I want my local master to track the remote master.

The *proper* way to do this isn't clear to me, and I've been unable to determine it from the documentation, even though it shouldn't really be more than one command.

Because it's something that's only ever done once per repository, I've generally employed one of two simple, but hacky, solutions:

1. used `git clone` to make a new local repository, and deleted the old one. After git cloning, the new repository is setup to track the origin.
2. manually edited .git/config to make master track origin.

I think I should be able to run a command, probably some form of `git remote` to setup an existing repository to have master track a remote master. Can anyone tell me what that command is?

Comment: Actually turns out that a similar question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312055/how-do-i-fix-missing-git-remote-details

Comment: For git version >= 1.7.0.0 you can do it in one command, it's explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch).

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/456814).

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Use the set-upstream arg:

```
git branch --set-upstream local-branch-name origin/remote-branch-name
```

Running the above command updates your .git/config file correctly and even verifies with this output:

*"Branch local-branch-name set up to track remote branch remote-branch-name from origin."*

**EDIT:** As [martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951064/martijn) said: "In version Git v1.8.0, --set-upstream is deprecated. Use --set-upstream-to instead."

```
git branch --set-upstream-to local-branch-name origin/remote-branch-name
```

See [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) for more information.

Comment: In version Git v1.8.0, `--set-upstream` is deprecated. Use `--set-upstream-to` instead.

Comment: Use `git remote show <remote>` to see which branches are tracked by your local branches

Comment: [This suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4688186) shouldn't have been approved, it fundamentally changed the answer (and left it in an incorrect state, since the arguments to the new option are reversed). Let the original poster decide whether or not he wants to update his answer.

Comment: You could also push the branch again with `git push -u`

Comment: Doesn't `set upstream` set up the mappings without actually pushing up any code? push forces you to push code to create mappings. Maybe you have no code yet, but want to establish a mapping?

Comment: You can use also use it like `git branch -u localBranchName upstream/remoteBranchName`. Or you can just `git branch -u upstream/remoteBranchName` to change the upstream tracking on the current branch you run the command on.

Answer (score 19):

`git help remote` should show you what you need to know.  I think what you want is

```
git remote add [remote-name] [remote-url]

# Set a local branch to follow the remote
git config branch.[branch-name].remote [remote-name]

# Set it to automatically merge with a specific remote branch when you pull
git config branch.[branch-name].merge [remote-master]
```

You can also manually edit .git/config to set these up.

Comment: Another option is to make your central repository, then delete your working directory and recreate it by cloning from the central repository.  Editing .git/config will be more informative, though.

Comment: cloning the central repository and editing .git/config are the two options I already mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use this if you want to create a new local branch to track a remote branch:

```
git checkout --track -b [branch_name] --track origin[or other remote name]/[remote_branch_name]
```

or even better:

```
git checkout -t origin/branch_name
```

Comment: git checkout --track -b branchname origin branchname
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/branchname' which can not be resolved as commit?

Answer (score 11):

On newer versions of git you can use

```
git branch --track origin/branch_name
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: This is the most accurate answer!
All of the above are not incorrect or no longer supported `git branch --set-upstream BRANCH
fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. Please use '--track' or '--set-upstream-to' instead.`

Comment: @GTodorov just read the FULL accepted answer and you will see that now you have to use --set-upstream-to

Answer (score 4):

`The --set-upstream flag is deprecated and will be removed.`

`git branch master --set-upstream-to myupstream/master`

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward three years (see what I did there :-) ), I tried to pull an untracked branch using Git Bash and received

`If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:`

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> develop
```

The following achieved what I needed:

`$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop develop
Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'origin'.`

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```sh
git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]
```

Comment: Hi, you might want to re-read the question - it mentions cloning the repository again, but the question is about when the local repository was created first and didn't initially track the remote.