# How to make existing git branch track a remote branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

> Possible duplicate: [Getting existing git branches to track remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184518/1065190)

I know how to make a new branch that tracks remote branches. But how do I make an existing branch track a remote branch. I know I can just edit the .git/config file but it seems there should be an easier way.

Comment: You can push your branch into remote branch with `-u` option

Answer (score 5):

There are many solutions to this task.

**1. Manual update**

You can open the `.git/config` file and add the definition of your branch:

```
[branch "myfeature"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/myfeature
```

Now your existing branch `myfeature` will track the remote branch `refs/heads/myfeature` from `origin`.

**2. Using `branch` command**

Another way is to use the `set-upstream` of the `branch` command:

```
git branch --set-upstream <your-branch> origin/<remote-branch>
```

It will update your `.git/config` file.