# Why not able to push the new added files on remote repository?

Tags: linux, git, github, command-line, git-bash

I am new to Git. I have recently created a repository and uploaded a folder in it using the following sequence of commands:

```
$ git init
$ git add <file name>
$ git commit -m "some comment"
$ git branch -M main
$ git remote add origin <url>
$ git push -u origin main
```

This was my first time when I uploaded the files to this repository. Now I am trying to upload more files to this repository using the following commands:

```
$ git add <file name>
$ git commit -m "some comment"
$ git branch -M main
$ git push -u origin main
```

But, I am getting the following information:

```
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date
```

Why is it so? How can I upload more files on my repository using git in the command line?
Please resolve it.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi please check answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184518/getting-existing-git-branches-to-track-remote-branches

Comment: In general, you should only do the `git branch -M main` *once*, when you first create the repository. And, in general, once you have run `git push -u origin main` *once*, you do not need the `-u` here any more. You will need it for *other* branch names, *once per branch name*. The real problem was that you forgot to commit, though, as you found and noted under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is causing you're specific problem here, but i think you are not following the correct workflow. These are the steps you should follow:

1. Type git branch and ensure that you are on the main branch (if not do git checkout main)
2. Then do:

   ```
   git add <file>
   git commit -m "comment"
   git push -u origin main
   ```

Follow this flow everytime you want to push to this branch and you should have no issues.

Comment: its not working in your way too, I am getting the same result.

Comment: Type git status and see if there are any changes to be committed. It might be that there are no changes in the files you are trying to add/commit

Comment: yes it is showing for one file to commit changes, but don't know why it is not working

Comment: Can you share the result of git status

Comment: thank you the problem has been solved, I had forgotten to commit the changes before pushing it.